# Minecraft: Making spheres

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like to create some aesthetic structures in Minecraft and am particularly interested in making some floating spheres. Are there templates, tips, tricks, or other methods anyone has found on the best ways to construct them? I'm thinking spheres with a diameter of 10 blocks for starters.